# How to change the background color in Notepad2

Tags: notepad++, editor, notepad2

I recently switched from notepad++ to the new kid in the block [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html). But i am finding it difficult to find a way to change the background color of the editor to a dark theme as i used in notepad ++

I ve searched Google and SO but havent come across anything that states whether it is possible(If so how?) or not

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Goto

```
1.menu --> view --> Customize Schemes
2.Double click Default Text
3.Select Default Style
4.Click Back.. Button and set color
```

Thats all

Answer (score 2):

i wrote a little tool that does this, here: https://github.com/piersh/InvertNotepad2

Comment: Hey, could you perhaps write a tool that converts the Notepad++ themes into Notepad2 themes? Notepad++ has many mores, and I'd like to use some of them with Notepad2 but I have no idea how to do the xml into ini =(